# Can this weird function be directly calculated?

Tags: c, math, optimization

I'd like the calculate this function directly, but the trick has eluded me so far:

```
uint8_t distance(uint64_t a, uint8_t b) {
    // a and b both odd, a at least as large as b 
    assert((a & 1) && (b & 1) && a >= b);  
    // really dumb, keep subtracting 2 until you hit a multiple of b
    uint64_t distance = 0;
    while (a % b != 0) {
        distance++;
        a -= 2;
    }
    assert(distance <= 255);
    return (uint8_t)distance;
}
```

Basically the return value is how many times `a` has to be decremented by 2 to be a multiple of `b`. This should be true eventually (without wraparound or anything weird) since `a` and `b` are odd and `a >= b`.

If it was "decrement by 1" rather than by 2 the answer would be a simple `%`...

Performance matters in this case (so for example avoiding unpredictable branches would be nice).

Comment: See the first `assert()` which ensures both `a` and `b` are always odd. This function is only ever passed odd values.

Comment: Why did you change your function? With removing `a-=2;` you change the result of your function and make every answer useless!

Comment: @Gerhardh - because the accepted answer didn't include it (technically, it was incorrect), and it's somewhat pointless in that I can't imagine an interesting solution that relies on it somehow. To be very there are exactly two answers, and the better (overall) one didn't have it and the other one did. In any case, your are right that I should have fixed up the other answer after that change and I've done so now.

Comment: Did you verify that it produces the exact same result?

Comment: @Gerhardh: Looking at the original version again, the extra `a -= 2;` produced a different result from what the English description text said the function should do, so either the code or the description had to change. (My answer was based on the English description.)

Comment: Which English description are you talking about? There is not description in your question but only a function you asked to be improved.

Comment: If the accepcted answer does not produce exactly the same result, then it is simply not an answer to your question.

Comment: Yes. I originally verified the function in the accepted answer against a version of my function without the `a -= 2`, since I noted that this line had been missed, and it produces the correct result, at least for all possible `b` and many `a` values. Obviously I can add the `a -= 2` by hand...

Comment: @Gerhardh - yes "If the accepcted answer does not produce exactly the same result, then it is simply not an answer to your question" ... if you are an annoying pedant. A more reasonable person might note the answerer overlooked a minor detail (and indeed a detail that the english language description omitted) and fix it up. That's what I did.

Comment: Again, which description do you mean? You only provided code. If the answer fixed your bugs, there must be some hidden information you didn' share.

Comment: I believe @user2357112 is referring to the description right below the code: _Basically the return value is how many times a has to be decremented by 2 to be a multiple of b._ Technically the original description should have read something like _Basically the return value is how many times **a minus 2** has to be decremented by 2 to be a multiple of b._ to be an exact match to the original code.

Comment: @Gerhardh - I have no idea what you mean about "If the answer fixed your bugs, there must be some hidden information you didn' share.". The answerer did not fix my bugs. The original function is the one I needed, due to an odd contract where the caller passes in a value 2 higher than how I would have defined the function if I had written it, so it has this `a -= 2` "fixup" since it was easier to do it there than change every caller. That made it into the question, and I considered removing it since it is not _at all interesting_ in that the meat of the question is the following part.

Comment: I decided to leave it in though, because the question was valid either way, and who knows, maybe in there is some minuscule possibility that the `a -= 2` version would somehow look different (really minuscule). Then, the accepted solution, which showed up within half and hour overlooked that minor detail, not unreasonable if you focused on the core loop and the original description. I noted to myself the discrepancy, and accounted for it while validating.

Comment: Today, since no better solution as appeared (and I don't think there will be a _much_ better once since the `%` probably can't be gotten rid of), I decided to accept this fine solution but I didn't want to be in the situation of accepting the answer that technically didn't match the output of my function with modification. I could either edit the answer, or my question. Had there been a great deal of other answers also including the `a -= 2` part, no doubt I would have left well enough alone and edited the answer, but since there was only one (much worse) answer, I edited the accepted answer.

Comment: This leaves both the question and answer simpler and cleaner. Yes, I forgot to edit the other user's answer, but I've fixed that now. Are you satisfied that it's all above board now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `a % b` is even, the result is `(a % b) / 2`. Otherwise, it's `(a % b + b) / 2`. You can microoptimize this if you want, but a straightforward implementation is

```
if ((a % b) % 2 == 0) {
    return (a % b) / 2;
} else {
    return (a % b + b) / 2;
}
```

I won't give you a specific microoptimized version, because that's something you should really profile yourself in the context of your application.

Comment: One possible set of microoptimizations involves using the standard `div()` family of functions — probably `lldiv()` — as long as `a` will never be bigger than `INT64_MAX`.  (I'm left wondering why most function names get the `l` or `ll` as a suffix, but these get it as a prefix  I guess it is probably precedent; that's what was in the field when the standard was created.  Oh well, so much for consistency.)

Comment: Also define this function as `inline` to give the compiler a chance to optimize the modulos into multiplications for contant values of `b`.

Comment: Microoptimized version is not worth it: the compiler already generates code without any jumps: https://godbolt.org/g/QUdmNs

Comment: Well on [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/Ji7JEc) it uses a jump, but not for the branch visible in the code, but apparently to issue a 32-bit division if the top bits of `a` are all zero. Kind of interesting and I haven't noticed this before. On Skylake, for example, 32-bit divisions can issue once every 6 cycles, but 64-bit vary from once every 21 to 83 cycles (although values with the top bits zero are probably near the end of that range), so that could win big if the non-zero part is often 32-bits or smaller.

Comment: @chqrlie - you don't need to declare it inline for that to work, as [this example](https://godbolt.org/g/iQXAkd) shows. Of course inline can help avoid the duplicate definitions you'd end up with otherwise if you included it in multiple files (but so can `static`), and it may serve as a _hint_ that the function is smart to inline.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: good point. Depending on the compiler, `static inline`, `extern inline`, definition before use, or simply definition in the same module may allow the compiler to inline the code and optimize special cases. `inline` seems needed to avoid dead code, but a global link-time optimizer would avoid that too.

Comment: Yeah I kind of got turned off of plain `inline` because of the C rules about requiring an out-of-line definition somewhere, which if left out usually doesn't cause a problem until some random optimization decision, new compiler or compiler flag suddenly causes a link error, so I usually use `static inline` for multiply included function in an `.h` that may inline, or just a single definition in `.c` file otherwise.